# Error building a function to calculate standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, function, statistics

I am new to Python and I am trying to build a function to run some statistics on a data set. The data is in an Excel format and it contains 7 rows, with the first row I know what a function is and how it should be built, nevertheless I can't figure it out how to build this function.

This is the function:

```
def st_dev(benchmark, factor):

    benchmark = mkt_ret
    factor = smb
    statistics = st.stdev(benchmark, factor)

return statistics


print(st_dev)
```

And this is the result:

```
        Mkt-RF   SMB   HML   RMW   CMA    RF
196307  -0.39 -0.46 -0.81  0.72 -1.16  0.27
196308   5.07 -0.81  1.65  0.42  -0.4  0.25
196309  -1.57 -0.48  0.19  -0.8  0.23  0.27
196310   2.53 -1.29 -0.09  2.75 -2.26  0.29
196311  -0.85 -0.85  1.71 -0.34  2.22  0.27
4.38
<function st_dev at 0x0000000002D92F28>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

the full code can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/hermeneanu/7067a1a11f4f550d8b1fd36636de3d5c).

I tried several versions to write the function, some error messages told me that I cannot convert 'Series' to numerator/denominator.

I am running python 3.7

Thank you for your help.

Alex

Comment: try to provide a [mcve] here on SO instead of linking a github repo

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you provide some minimal, verfiable code and data example? *Please edit your question accordingly.* For guidance check the link in the previous comment. Thank you

Comment: I hope this provides more clarity. Thank you.